# tp-link device not listed on nmcli

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, networkmanager

I've installed a tp-link usb device, in addition to the built-in wifi device, and I can see it on ifconfig after running `sudo ifconfig ra0 up`:

```
ra0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:3e:aa:ac:18:3f  
          inet6 addr: fe80::523e:aaff:feac:183f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4906 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2932 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1254425 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:211392 (211.3 KB)
```

However it's not listed on nmcli:

```
$ nmcli d
DEVICE     TYPE              STATE        
E0:AA:96:7E:E2:AD bluetooth         disconnected 
5C:51:81:24:59:74 bluetooth         disconnected 
58:3F:54:3F:0A:54 bluetooth         disconnected 
wlan0      802-11-wireless   connected    
eth0       802-3-ethernet    unavailable
```

What am I missing?

---

#### EDIT

lsusb output:

```
$ sudo lsusb -vd 148f:761a

Bus 002 Device 006: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.01
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x148f Ralink Technology, Corp.
  idProduct          0x761a 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 MediaTek
  iProduct                2 WiFi
  iSerial                 3 1.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           74
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              160mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           8
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x08  EP 8 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x07  EP 7 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x09  EP 9 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength           12
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Comment: What does command: lsusb output?

Comment: @Gordon I've added lsusb output to the question.

Comment: What's the model number, it is possible that it's not compatible with Linux

Comment: @Gordon the model is AC600, and you can also look up the [USB vendor/device ID](https://devicehunt.com/search/type/usb/vendor/148F/device/761A). I've installed a Linux driver for it, maybe I should try a different driver.